# Mouse cursor keeps swapping back and forth, how do I fix?

Tags: mouse, cursor, ubuntu-gnome, cursor-theme

This is in Gnome, which uses the Adwaita cursor theme on default. I don't particularly care for Adwaita so I replaced with Dmz-white, which is now currently on default. However the mouse will swap back to Adwaita briefly when certain things occur, like when something is loading or when I'm re-sizing a window. This also happened on standard Ubuntu as well, when I changed the cursor theme. Restarting hasn't changed anything nor has swapping them back and forth. It's incredibly annoying and I'm assuming and hoping that it's an easy fix.

Comment: I think I've seen Google Chrome use the default pointer instead of the themed one. Does this also apply to you?

Comment: I don't use chrome, so I don't know about that. However I've notice it only occurs in particular apps and what changes is different for each app. Like it only changes loading animation and resize animation in Nautilus to Adwaita, but not for terminal. However in terminal the drag animation is Adwaitas, not Dmz.